# Basic Counting Question

Tags: combinatorics

I'd just like to get the answer to this question checked by someone. You are buying cups from a vendor that sells cups in four different colors - blue, green, yellow, and red. You would like to buy ten cups. How many different ways can you purchase ten cups? Order doesn't matter and there is no requirement that you buy a certain number of any color. For example, you could buy all green cups or nine blue and one red.

I think that the answer is $4^{10} = 1048576$ since you can treat buying each cup as an independent event and simply multiply the number of combinations per event.

Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 3):

No, that doesn't seem right.

You said yourself that order doesn't matter. However, by considering "buying each cup" as an independent event, buying 9 reds then a blue cup is considered distinct from buying the blue cup first *then* the 9 reds, when you actually want to count them as the same.

If we view this abstractly, you have $$x_b + x_g + x_y + x_r = 10$$ with $x_b, x_g, x_y, x_r \geq 0$. This then, is just a [stars and bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) with $n = 4, k = 10$. The answer is then $$\binom{13}{10} = 286$$

Comment: (If you follow the link, look at "Theorem two")